React to return value of a function not working properly
I'd like to react to return value of a function, but my code is not working properly:
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo $(sudo pacman -Rcs "$(pacman -Qdtq)")
if [[ $(sudo pacman -Rcs "$(pacman -Qdtq)") == "Error:"* ]]; then
     echo -e "Nothing found."
     exit
else
   echo -e "still running ..."
   sudo pacman -Rcs "$(pacman -Qdtq)"
   echo $?
fi

The code returns:
Error: nothing found: 

Error: nothing found: 
still running ...
Error: nothing found: 
1

How to make the if condition work properly?

Probably if the command output is "Error: ..." then it's printed to stderr, not stdout. $() will only capture stdout. Also the command will probably exit with a nonzero status so you may be able to use that instead of reading the output.

Hmm, the result of
'''echo $(sudo pacman -Rcs "$(pacman -Qdtq)")
is Error ... Why the IF-command is not working?

Define what you mean by "result". If you mean "output", then, what you see is the mix of stdout and stderr, and you can catch them and use the captured part for comparision. Your code captures only stdout. Aside from the this, your reference to "function" is misleading. I don't think that pacman is a function.

If I fire in konsole
'''echo $(sudo pacman -Rcs "$(pacman -Qdtq)")
it returns "Error". Anyway: how to make my code react to this result? May be, sudo is the the problem?

No, sudo is not the problem. The comments you received so far are telling you what the problem is (stderr vs stdout) and suggesting solutions (capture stderr or use exit status). By the way - nothing in Unix "returns" anything. Unix commands/scripts/functions produce output and exit with a status so when you talk about what anything "returns" it's unclear if you're referring to its output or it's exit status. So, just say output or exit status instead of return going forward for clarity and if it's output state if it's to stdout or stderr or elsewhere.

[edit] your question to add the output of these 2 commands so we can check if the suggestions above are correct and then help you further: 1) sudo pacman -Rcs "$(pacman -Qdtq)" >/dev/null; echo "$?" 2) sudo pacman -Rcs "$(pacman -Qdtq)" 2>/dev/null; echo "$?"

Crazy:
$ sudo pacman -Rcs "$(pacman -Qdtq)" >/dev/null
Error: not found...
$ echo "$?"
1
$ sudo pacman -Rcs "$(pacman -Qdtq)" 2>/dev/null
$ echo "$?"
1

A complete command of the form echo $(some command without redirections) is almost always inferior to just some command without redirections.  The first form captures the inner command's standard output and then just turns around and passes it as arguments to echo.  Why capture and re-output instead of just letting the inner command's output just go straight through?

I had asked you to [edit] your question to include that output, not put it in a comment where it can't be formatted and could be missed. Anyway, that confirms the Error message is going to stderr, not stdout, and that you could test for a non-zero exit status instead of testing the output.

From what you've told us so far it sounds like this would do what your code appears to be trying to do:
#!/bin/bash
clear

if sudo pacman -Rcs "$(pacman -Qdtq)"; then
   echo -e "still running ..."
   sudo pacman -Rcs "$(pacman -Qdtq)"
   echo $?
else
   echo -e "Nothing found."
   exit
fi

I don't know why you want that second call to pacman inside the success case so I just left it there.
The main problem in your code is that the Error message from pacman is going to stderr, but your == comparison is testing what's printed to stdout.
